# Buttons not properly placed were suppose to be placed. CSS. HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I faced this problem where when I put the 'home' '1st series' 'contact us' and so on into the css , the website duplicates the banner that I have inserted and puts the 'home' button where it is suppose to be and the other buttons onto the duplicated banner.I have put a screenshot at the very end to show you clearly how this is coming(or you could click the number 1 right here) -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVs5m.jpg) I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please can someone tell me what may be the problem?

```
Below is the code:
```

```css
#container{
   width: 1200px;
   margin: auto;
   padding-left: 100px;
   padding-right: 100px; 

    body{
    background-color: lightgray;
  font-family: arial;
    }

    header{
  background-image: url("Images/Tv Shows Banner.PNG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 250px;
  width:1200px;
  padding-right:50px;
  padding-left:100px;
  background-position: middle;


    }

    h1{
     color: white;
     padding-left: 350px;
     padding-top: 80px;
    float: right-side;
    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 50px;
    }
    nav {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    nav a:link, nav a:visited {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: white; 
       margin: 10px;
       padding: 5px;         
    }

    nav a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   border-radius: 20px;
```

```html
<html> 
       <head>
        <title>Top 5 Tv Series </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Top 5 Tv Series CSS.css">
       </head>
        <body>
      <div id="container">
     <header>
      <h1>Top 5 TV Series</h1>
       <img id="Banner" src="Images/Tv Shows Banner.PNG"/>
      </header>
   
      <nav> 
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">1st Series</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">2nd Series</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">3rd Series</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">4th Series</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">5th Series</a>
        <a href="Top 5 Tv Series.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you using any JS code to duplicate/clone the banner? I didn't find any code which is replicating the banner

Comment: No I am not using any JavaScript code

Comment: I have exactly copy paste your code, with just change of image src. Check this codepen link : https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/PaPyPv

Comment: Edit the codepen with the css properties you are using and comment with the updated codepen link

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to intend here

Comment: What I wanted to say is, the code you have posted in your question is not sufficient to recreate the problem you are facing. Hence I have given the codepen link, where you can edit the code and show exactly at what point you are facing the issue. Using the code you have given I didn;t find any error.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: You are welcome! But,I didn't think that I have helped you to resolve the issue. If you are still facing the same problem, create a codepen or jsfiddle for us to check and help you.

Comment: I have put the code into the codepen and arranged the errors but there is still the same output. This is the codepen : https://codepen.io/chrizana-mizzi/pen/mKezwY

Comment: I checked your code and the issue is the "height:250px;" which you are giving for "header". Remove the header height and check.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help